# ICC profile contains 1 component while the image data contains 3 components

Tags: java, itext7

While trying to add images to PDF using itext 7, I get following error:
(This error comes for some images. I can write other images successfully.)

```
ERROR 4868com.itextpdf.io.IOException: ICC profile contains 1 components, while the image data contains 3 components.
    at com.itextpdf.io.color.IccProfile.getInstance(IccProfile.java:90)
    at com.itextpdf.io.image.JpegImageHelper.processParameters(JpegImageHelper.java:370)
    at com.itextpdf.io.image.JpegImageHelper.processImage(JpegImageHelper.java:142)
    at com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory.createImageInstance(ImageDataFactory.java:524)
    at com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory.create(ImageDataFactory.java:101)
    at com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory.create(ImageDataFactory.java:121)
    at com.itextpdf.io.image.ImageDataFactory.create(ImageDataFactory.java:131)
```

Below is the code I use:

```
Cell cell = new Cell(1, 1);
Image image = new Image(ImageDataFactory.create(photoLocation));
image.setWidth(58);
image.setHeight(58f);
cell.add(image);
```

Same image used to work with iText5.

Comment: The root cause is most likely that the image contains an ICC profile detailing 3 components, but the image itself is grayscale. Most likely due to the image being converted to grayscale and the conversion program not modifiyng the profile. In iText5 the check happens but the image gets added anyway. Fixing the source image is probably the cleanest solution

Comment: @Samuel Huylebroeck I used imagemagick to correct the images. It worked for most of the images (3003 images out of 3035). But for some images (32 to be exact) even after using imagemagick, I am still getting the same error. When I user imagemagick's convert command on these 32 images, command runs without any error. How could I fix those images.

Comment: No clue, at least no without having access to the images in question. I suggest inspecting them, visually and structurally to find out how they differ from the images for which the conversion does work.

Answer (score 0):

> Tried to Recreate the Scenario [but showing 4 components]

[image]

> And after Resolving

[image]

**The process i followed:**

converting https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxVET.jpg to gray say (penguin_gray)
On penguin_gray

using -set colorspace to convert to penguin_result[CMYK]

```
magick convert penguin_gray.jpg -set colorspace CMYK penguin_result.jpg
```

this gives the failure scenario

Now on the same penguin_gray

Using -colorspace to convert to penguin_result[CMYK]

```
magick convert penguin_gray.jpg -colorspace CMYK penguin_result.jpg
```

This gives you the Success Scenario

This might not solve your case[because as it is showing only 3 components , unlike the image that i used showing 4 components]
But this can lead you to solve your case

if possible can u post those images ,will try to solve

Ref:http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?t=17207

Thanks

Comment: There's just an extra space in the file name. It should be `magick convert penguin_gray.jpg -set colorspace CMYK penguin_result.jpg`. This answer works. I had this issue - ICC profile contains 4 components while the image data contains 3 components.
 Thank you!